# FastAPI Mock is not working, Seems like that patch is not applied

Tags: python, mocking, fastapi

Would you please tell me what's wrong with this code?
app.py

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import status
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app_dep import resp
app = FastAPI()
client = TestClient(app)


def test_create_item(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        'app_dep.resp',
        return_value={'name', 'mocked'}
    )
    r = client.post("/ehsan")
    print(r.json())


@app.post("/ehsan", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create():
    return resp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("boot:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8100, reload=True)
```

app_dep.py

```
def resp():
    return {"name": "original"}
```

This is a whole code including a FastAPI app and a test. It is expected when I run `pytest app.py -s` see this output:

```
{'name': 'mocked'}
```

But I see:

```
{'name': 'original'}
```

Comment: `create` isn't a method on `app`, so your mock won't find anything useful to patch as far as I can tell; however, there generally isn't much reason to mock methods when testing FastAPI, instead you override dependencies as necessary for testing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatsLindh I just started using mocking, I want to test it. How to change this code to work?

Comment: Call it: there is no need to mock something like this, unless you're writing tests for a client. And in that case there is no need for FastAPI. Call the endpoint and make sure that it return the expected response: calling a mocked endpoint only demonstrates that your mock and FastAPI works as expected; which is not really the goal of the tests you write.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927965/1557060) answer helps you getting started?

Comment: @MatsLindh Question updated. actually the problem insists when object is inside another file

Comment: @JarroVGIT I did it that way but I think the problem is related for being in different files. question updated.

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi pytest already has monkeypatch from the box, so there is no need to use mocker. See [this article](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html)

Comment: @sudden_appearance I tried that article, the same result. I think it's something related to different files.